# Sofort Payment with Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I want help to implement sofort payment with android?

I am having this error

E/Volley: [5725] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://api.sofort.com/api/

Comment: see this https://www.sofort.com/integrationCenter-ger-DE/integration/API-SDK/

Comment: can u help with a code please

Comment: do you want to connect Stripe ?

Comment: ich möchte das sofortüberweisung verwenden. mit welchem Provider ist mir egal. Das Problem ich komme nicht klar mit dem Code

Comment: Klar wollte ich auch mastercard und visa anwenden. Bitte um Hilfe

Comment: i want to use Sofortüberweisung of Klarna with android Studio 
I do not know how to program this

Comment: i want to use mastercard and visa

Comment: Klarna and Stripe together

Comment: @MiltonMakelaEssome - Brother had you implemented Sofort in Android?